# Sonarqube show bugs number error in c# project

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I want to install sonarqube. And I want to see bug etc in my C# project.

But I didn't get results. Can you help me with why I can't?

1. Install download sonarqube.
2. Install ms build sonar-scanner.
3. I write sonar.project-properties and scanner into the bin file.

   ```
   sonar.projectKey= //projectkey
   sonar.projectName= //this same projectkey
   sonar.projectVersion=1.0
   ```
4. This project is put bin file.
5. I added the scanner to path path.
6. Enter localhost
7. Create project and enter project key and name (same as name and key in txt)

But this project is empty even though My project is passed.
The code appears when I enter the code section but fields like bug vurnelabilities don't appear.**Bugs,vulnerabilities,code smells show zero but passed solution.I know it's the error so I can't 0**

I want to appear with the error of my project code there bugs appear areas etc. **But "this project is empty" looks like "passed "**

**Shouldn't code errors appear here?Why can't I see?**

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of [SonarLint for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.SonarLintforVisualStudio2017)

Answer (score 1):

To scan your C# code and push the results to SonarQube you need to use the [SonarScanner for MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild), not the [SonarScanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner).

SonarLint is a Visual Studio extension that runs the SonarC# and SonarVB.Net analyzers in the IDE. It does not push the results to SonarQube.
SonarLint is available for [VS2015 Update 3](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.SonarLintforVisualStudio) and [VS2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.SonarLintforVisualStudio2017).

Comment: Thanks for your answers.I learned with your answers. Msbuild use vs2015 update 3 and vs 2017 so I dont use sonerqube.Thank you.